# Javascript replace all characters that are not a-z OR apostrophe

Tags: javascript, regex

I have look around the interwebs but I have yet to find a solid answer. This seems pretty straight forward. Let say I want to replace all characters in a string that is NOT a-z and NOT and apostrophe. For example:

with the string "jeni's splendid ice cream" i would like to replace all characters that are NOT a-z OR an apostrophe. What i have tried so far is:

```
var term = "jeni's splendid ice cream"
term.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]|[^\']/g, '');
```

But that didn't seem to work.... Does that look correct to everyone? Just need to sanity check, lol

Comment: I believe part of your problem is you're not setting the value of 'term' back to itself as part of the operation: term = term.toLowerCase()...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are looking for basically anything. Your regex is roughly equal to:

```
if (character !== 'value1' || character !== 'value2')
```

Therefore, anything works. You need to instead include the apostrophe in the regex bracket group:

```
/[^a-z']/g
```

Also, as [Steve Hynding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30179194/javascript-replace-all-characters-that-are-not-a-z-or-apostrophe/30179224#comment48464362_30179194) points out, you never actually change the value of `term`. To make the code work as you expect, it should be rewritten as:

```
var term = "jeni's splendid ice cream"
term = term.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z']/g, '');
```

Answer (score 4):

Or statements (`|`) belong inside the group, but in the case it is unnecessary. This regex should do the trick:

```
/[^a-z']/g
```

### Working Example:

```js
var term = "jeni's splendid ice cream"
alert(term.toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z']/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or something like this :

```
var term = "jeni's splendid ice cream";
term.replace(new RegExp('[^a-z\']', 'g'), '');
```